# How use second Table on Laravel Auth System

Tags: php, laravel

What method should I use when capturing user-specific data from a table other than the table created by the laravel auth system?

```
public function fonksiyonum($id)
{
$xler= Xmodel::WhereRaw('uye_id=? and durum=1',array($id))->get();

return view('profil',array('xler'=>$xler));
}


Route::get('/profil/{id}', array('as'=>'profil','uses'=>'xkontrol@fonksiyonum')->middleware('auth');
```

It happens this way, but I do not want to use get.
Just like in the auth system.

```
$id=Auth::user()->id
```

to display the data in the other table to the logged-in user

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you explain more ?

Comment: Change the route to `/profil/{xmodel}` so that Laravel attempts to implicitly resolve the model its self, then inject it as a dependency to your function `public function fonksiyonum(Xmodel $xler)` If you need to supply custom arguments to resolve the model, then explicitly bind it in your `RouteServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package:

Step 1: Install Through Composer

composer require hesto/multi-auth

Step 2: Add the Service Provider (only for laravel lower than 5.5)

You'll only want to use these package for local development, so you don't want to update the production providers array in config/app.php. Instead, add the provider in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php, like so:

```
      public function register()
 {
if ($this->app->environment() == 'local') {
    $this->app->register('Hesto\MultiAuth\MultiAuthServiceProvider');
}
  }
```

Step 3: Install Multi-Auth files in your project

```
      php artisan multi-auth:install {singular_lowercase_name_of_guard} -f
```

// Examples
            php artisan multi-auth:install admin -f
            php artisan multi-auth:install employee -f
            php artisan multi-auth:install customer -f

Notice: If you don't provide -f flag, it will not work. It is a protection against accidental activation.

Alternative:

If you want to install Multi-Auth files in a subdomain you must pass the option --domain.

```
     php artisan multi-auth:install admin -f --domain
     php artisan multi-auth:install employee -f --domain
     php artisan multi-auth:install customer -f --domain
```

To be able to use this feature properly, you should add a key to your .env file:

```
     APP_DOMAIN=yourdomain.com
```

This will allow us to use it in the routes file, prefixing it with the domain feature from Laravel routing system.

Using it like so: ['domain' => '{guard}.' . env('APP_DOMAIN')]

Step 4: Migrate new model table

```
    php artisan migrate
```

Step 5: Try it

```
     Go to: http://project_url/GuardName/login

      Example: http://myproject.dev/customer/login
```

Options
If you don't want model and migration use --model flag.

```
   php artisan multi-auth:install admin -f --model
```

If you don't want views use --views flag.

```
   php artisan multi-auth:install admin -f --views
```

If you don't want routes in your routes/web.php file, use --routes flag.

```
   php artisan multi-auth:install admin -f --routes
```